# Time complexity of concatenating/copying two vectors

Tags: c++, vector, copy, time-complexity, concatenation

`vector1.insert( vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end() );`

What will be the **Time complexity** of concatenating/copying two vectors?

Comment: Sounds like a test question. What do you think it is? Why?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Short answer "O(n)"

Answer (score 2):

From the standard [[vector.modifiers]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.modifiers):

> *Complexity*: If reallocation happens, linear in the number of elements
> of the resulting vector; otherwise, linear in the number of elements
> inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector.